# Calling en.yml constants from views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

```
Rails 5.2
SimpleForm
```

I am looking at the source code, of a sample-form_bootstrap, to learn more about Rails.

In the en.yml file, I see:

```
  simple_form:
    labels:
      user:
        email: Email
        first_kiss: First kiss
    hints:
      user:
        name: Text input example
        email: We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        password: Password input example
        color: Collection as inline radio buttons example
        fruit: Collection as inline check boxes example
    options:
      user:
        color:
          red: Red
          pink: Pink
          violet: Violet
          indigo: Indigo
          blue: Blue
          teal: Teal
          green: Green
          yellow: Yellow
        fruit:
          apple: Apple
          banana: Banana
          cherry: Cherry
          coconut: Coconut
          grape: Grape
          lime: Lime
          mango: Mango
          orange: Orange
          pear: Pear
          pineapple: Pineapple
```

If I do:

```
User::COLOR
```

I get:

```
 [:red, :pink, :violet, :indigo, :blue, :teal, :green, :yellow]
```

But, if I try something like:

```
SimpleForm::LABELS
```

I get an uninitialized constant error SimpleForm::LABELS

What are the rules, for how to call the constants from en.ym, from my views, especially collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked out [SimpleForm](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap) documentation actually `User::COLOR` is a constant in `user` model not loading it from `en`.

You're getting **uninitialized constant error SimpleForm::LABELS** because there is no constant defined on it.

If you want to define them to a constant and use them in you're views, you can do something like this:

In `app_config.rb` first read the `en.yml` file like this

```
info = Rails.root.to_s + '/config/locales/en.yml'
data = YAML.load_file(info).deep_symbolize_keys!
```

and then define a constant something like below,

```
LABELS = data[:simple_form][:labels]
```

So that you can LABELS constant across you're application.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this `en.yml` structure:

`en:
  simple_form:
    options:
      user:
        role:
          admin: 'Administrator'
          editor: 'Editor'`

For collections you can  use this `f.input :role, collection: [:admin, :editor]`. A complete guide present at [SimpleForm#I18n](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n)

Also, you can parse `YML` directly.

```
require 'yaml'
thing = YAML.load_file('en.yml') # Assuming your en.yml file here.
puts thing["simple_form"]["labels"]
```